# c++ destructor called too early

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, clang++

I have simplified the code to the smallest sample that still has the problem. This code should print "42", but instead prints a different number. I also print the address of the "Secret" object in the destructor, and when it is accessed, to show that it is being destructed too early. Am I doing something wrong here, or could this be a problem with the compiler?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;    

struct Secret{
    int value;
    Secret(int value):value(value){}
    ~Secret(){
        cout<<"destructor:"<<(void*)this<<endl;
        value=0;
    }
};    

template<class Func>
class Copier{
public:
    Func func;
    Copier(Func func):func(func){}
    void run(){
        func();
    }
    auto copy(){
        auto output = [this](){
            func();
        };
        Copier<decltype(output)> out(output);
        return out;
    }    

};
auto makeSecretPrinter(){
    Secret secret(42);
    auto secretPrinter = [secret](){
        cout<<"reading object at address:"<<(void*)&secret<<endl;
        cout<<"the secret is:"<<secret.value<<endl;
    };
    return Copier<decltype(secretPrinter)>(secretPrinter).copy();
}    

int main(){
    makeSecretPrinter().run();
    return 0;
}
```

clang (version 3.5-1ubuntu1) output:

```
destructor:0x7fff9e3f9940
destructor:0x7fff9e3f9938
destructor:0x7fff9e3f9948
destructor:0x7fff9e3f9950
reading object at address:0x7fff9e3f9940
the secret is:0
```

GCC (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2 output:

```
destructor:0x7fff374facc0
destructor:0x7fff374facb0
destructor:0x7fff374faca0
destructor:0x7fff374fac90
reading object at address:0x7fff374facc0
the secret is:-1711045632
```

Comment: Capturing `this` means to capture with pointer semantics. If the captured object is destroyed, you may not dereference that pointer (not even implicitly, as done in `copy`'s `output` lambda). Copying that lambda copies the captured pointer, i.e. performs a shallow copy.

Comment: `auto output = [this](){` this line seems like the problem. you really want to copy `*this` instead of a pointer

Comment: @BryanChen Exactly what I thought: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43b70f00c4a20469

Comment: Thanks @BryanChen, I didn't realize it was possible to capture *this in a lambda. That works perfectly!

Comment: The program has a problem.  See my answer below

Answer (score 3):

capturing `this` captures with pointer semantics. Changing this:

```
auto output = [this](){
    func();
};
```

to this fixes the problem:

```
auto output = [self=*this](){
    self.func();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The line: `makeSecretPrinter().run()`, it actually execute `makeSecretPrinter()` first, and then execute `run()`.  However, when `run()` is executing, it's already out of the scope of `makeSecretPrinter()`.  Thus the lambda function does not get correct value as the parameter to call.

Note that your class is receiving the function pointer only (or function reference, they are the same in semantics.)  This means the value is not passed into the `Copier` class.  When `Copier` tries to 'run()', it needs to pickup the variable in `makeSecretPrinter()`.  However, as I said, it's out of scope at the time when 'run()' is to be executed.